# when i run stored procedure manually it works fine , but when i run through SSRS it gets time out error

Tags: sql, reporting-services

when i run my stored procedure manually its working fine,

but when i trying to use the same stored procedure in SSRS report ,report getting time out error.

Comment: Welcome! Please take some time and reformat your question. The title is too long, and not very clear. And the description doesn't really describe the issue. Please give more detail, tell us what your setup looks like, and what you have tried. And give code examples! What's your store procedure look like?

Comment: Also, to see how SO works and how a good question looks like, take a look at the Tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour. Thanks!

Comment: The timeout could be on the SSRS portal. Also, you may want to think about optimizing the query in the stored procedure. More details would be a plus.

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html is chock-full of things to investigate. You really haven't given enough detail here for people to give concrete advice.